# Replace all slashes on a line with a match on at the beginning of the same line

Tags: javascript, regex, regexp-replace, regexp-substr

I'm trying to change all slashes on a line to replace with the 3-characters block at the beginninig of each line. (PMC,PAJ, etc in below example)

.**PMC**.89569XX/90051XX/90204XX/89533XX/90554XX/90053XX/90215XX/89874XX/89974XX/90481XX/90221XX/90508XX/90183XX/88526XX/89843XX/88041XX/90446XX/88515XX/89574XX/89847XX/88616XX/90513XX/90015XX/90334XX/89649XX.T00
.**PAJ**.77998XX/77896XX.T00
.**PAG**.78116XX/78104XX/77682XX/07616XX/77663XX/77863XX/07634XX/78088XX/77746XX/78148XX.T00
.**PKC**.22762XX/22358XX/22055XX/22672XX/22684XX/22154XX/22608XX/22768XX/22632XX/22266XX/22714XX/22658XX/22631XX/22288XX/22020XX/22735XX/22269XX/22138XX/22331XX/22387XX/22070XX/22636XX/22629XX/22487XX/22725XX.T00

The desired outcome should be:

PMC.89569XXPMC90051XXPMC90204XXPMC89533XXPMC90554XXPMC90053XXPMC90215XXPMC89874XXPMC89974XXPMC90481XXPMC90221XXPMC90508XXPMC90183XXPMC88526XXPMC89843XXPMC88041XXPMC90446XXPMC88515XXPMC89574XXPMC89847XXPMC88616XXPMC90513XXPMC90015XXPMC90334XXPMC89649XX.T00

I'm not sure how to accomplish this.
This is what I have so far:

```
 (.)([A-Z]{3})(.)(\/)
```

Comment: You want also remove first dot on each line?

Comment: In the end yes, the same goes for the 2nd dot

Comment: You may do it with a regex only, but only with ECMAScript2018 compliant regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you only plan to support ECMAScript 2018 and newer, you may achieve what you need with a single regex:

```
.replace(/(?<=^\.([^.]+)\..*?)\//g, "$1")
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EqKRRV/1).

**Details**

- `(?<=^\.([^.]+)\..*?)` - a positive lookbehind that, immediately to left of the current location, requires

  - `^` - start of string
  - `\.` - a dot
  - `([^.]+)` - Group 1: one or more chars other than a dot
  - `\.` - a dot
  - `.*?` - any 0+ chars, other than linebreak chars, as few as possible
- `\/` - a `/` char.

JS demo:

```js
var strs = ['.PMC.89569XX/90051XX/90204XX/89533XX/90554XX/90053XX/90215XX/89874XX/89974XX/90481XX/90221XX/90508XX/90183XX/88526XX/89843XX/88041XX/90446XX/88515XX/89574XX/89847XX/88616XX/90513XX/90015XX/90334XX/89649XX.T00','.PAJ.77998XX/77896XX.T00','.PAG.78116XX/78104XX/77682XX/07616XX/77663XX/77863XX/07634XX/78088XX/77746XX/78148XX.T00','.PKC.22762XX/22358XX/22055XX/22672XX/22684XX/22154XX/22608XX/22768XX/22632XX/22266XX/22714XX/22658XX/22631XX/22288XX/22020XX/22735XX/22269XX/22138XX/22331XX/22387XX/22070XX/22636XX/22629XX/22487XX/22725XX.T00'];
for (var s of strs) {
 console.log(s.replace(/(?<=^\.([^.]+)\..*?)\//g, "$1"));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Wiktor, this almost does the trick. Except it only works for the first line. 'PMC' not for the others at the same time 'PAJ' etc

Comment: @QAZ001 If you have to run it for a multiline string, use `m` modifier: `s.replace(/(?<=^\.([^.\n]+)\..*?)\//gm`. If there are any glitches, use `/(?<=(?:^|\n)\.([^.]+)\..*?)\//g`

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/VB232V/2, `(?:^|\n)` works better than the `^` with `m` modifier in this case.

Comment: Almost but still contains flaws. İt works fine upto PAJ. But than it starts to change PAG and PKC into PAJ's.

Comment: @QAZ001 It [actually works](https://regex101.com/r/VB232V/3), there is a problem with line breaks in your string. Just find them out and add to the `(?:^|[\n\r])` pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you can do it with just one regex and you will have to probably do it as a two step process. First, you can capture the three capital letters using `substring()` method and then you can replace all slashes with those three letter appearing in the beginning of character after first dot. Here is a demo with JS code,

```js
function transformLine(s) {
    var repStr = s.substring(1,4);
    var replacedStr = s.replace(/\//g, repStr);

    return replacedStr.substring(1,replacedStr.length);
}

var lines = [".PMC.89569XX/90051XX/90204XX/89533XX/90554XX/90053XX/90215XX/89874XX/89974XX/90481XX/90221XX/90508XX/90183XX/88526XX/89843XX/88041XX/90446XX/88515XX/89574XX/89847XX/88616XX/90513XX/90015XX/90334XX/89649XX.T00", ".PAJ.77998XX/77896XX.T00", ".PAG.78116XX/78104XX/77682XX/07616XX/77663XX/77863XX/07634XX/78088XX/77746XX/78148XX.T00", ".PKC.22762XX/22358XX/22055XX/22672XX/22684XX/22154XX/22608XX/22768XX/22632XX/22266XX/22714XX/22658XX/22631XX/22288XX/22020XX/22735XX/22269XX/22138XX/22331XX/22387XX/22070XX/22636XX/22629XX/22487XX/22725XX.T00"];

for (var i = 0;i<lines.length;i++) {
    console.log("Before: " + lines[i]);
    console.log("After: " + transformLine(lines[i])+"\n\n");
}
```

I've replaced the first dot as your expected output does not have it.

Let me know if this works for you.

**Edit:**

I have updated the code to provide a function that takes a string as input and returns the modified string. Please check the demo.

**Edit2: Solving it mostly using regex**

This one liner in the function does all the job for you in transforming your line to the required one.

```js
function transformLine(s) {
    return s.replace(/\//g, /^.(.{3})/.exec(s)[1]).replace(/^./,'');
}

var lines = [".PMC.89569XX/90051XX/90204XX/89533XX/90554XX/90053XX/90215XX/89874XX/89974XX/90481XX/90221XX/90508XX/90183XX/88526XX/89843XX/88041XX/90446XX/88515XX/89574XX/89847XX/88616XX/90513XX/90015XX/90334XX/89649XX.T00", ".PAJ.77998XX/77896XX.T00", ".PAG.78116XX/78104XX/77682XX/07616XX/77663XX/77863XX/07634XX/78088XX/77746XX/78148XX.T00", ".PKC.22762XX/22358XX/22055XX/22672XX/22684XX/22154XX/22608XX/22768XX/22632XX/22266XX/22714XX/22658XX/22631XX/22288XX/22020XX/22735XX/22269XX/22138XX/22331XX/22387XX/22070XX/22636XX/22629XX/22487XX/22725XX.T00"];

for (var i = 0;i<lines.length;i++) {
    console.log("Before: " + lines[i]);
    console.log("After: " + transformLine(lines[i])+"\n\n");
}
```

As you can see here, this line,

```
return s.replace(/\//g, /^.(.{3})/.exec(s)[1]).replace(/^./,'');
```

does all the job you need. It first extracts the three capital letter using this `/^.(.{3})/.exec(s)[1]` then all slashes are replaced with this captured word and then finally first character which is a dot is removed using this `/^./,''` and finally returns the string you need.

Let me know if this is what you wanted. Else let me know if you further wanted it in any particular way.

Comment: **I'm trying to change all slashes ... at the beginninig of each line** but your code work only for one line

Comment: @Mohammad: I have demonstrated it for one line and of course it can be done for any number of lines.

Comment: I was actually looking for a Regex only solution. It's no problem if multiple steps are necessary.

Comment: @QAZ001: Doing it with single regex didn't seem possible, as first you want to capture a string and then you want to replace any occurrence of slash with those three character word.

Comment: @Mohammad: I've engulfed my code into a function and run it for all lines through an array of string. Hope you wanted the same.

Comment: Any idea how to accomplish this in multipl eregex steps

Comment: Yes, you can do it in regex way. Let me update my answer with the one liner using regex which you can use to transform the lines.